# 'MySQL server has gone away' on Django 1.6.5

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064

I am running Django 1.6.5 with mysql (5.6.17).
Have the following DB settings in Django:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE'  : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME'    : '---REMOVED---',
        'USER'    : '---REMOVED---',
        'PASSWORD': '---REMOVED---',
        'HOST'    : '---REMOVED---',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': None
    }
}
```

Ever since upgrading to Django 1.6.5, I am plagued with the following error every few hours.

```
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

I have searched online and tried every timeout/sql size setting in MySQL and Django configuration that I could find on StackOverflow and nothing works :(

Can anyone suggest some new fresh ideas, things to test or point me in the right direction to find the root cause of this problem?

Comment: can you try removing mentioned line `'CONN_MAX_AGE': None`??

Comment: bhushya, when I added CONN_MAX_AGE the number of 'MySQL server has gone away' dropped. I think by default Django 1.6.5 closes the connection after each request while in the case with None keeps unlimited persistent connections.